# how to calculate worst-case time-complexity of this part of code

Tags: time-complexity

```
int pick1 = ran.nextInt(num)+1;
int pick2 = ran.nextInt(num)+1;
int pick3 = ran.nextInt(num)+1;

if(pick1!=pick2&&pick1!=pick3) {
    while(pick1!=pick2) {
        pick2=ran.nextInt(num)+1;
     }
     while(pick1!=pick3) {
        pick3=ran.nextInt(num)+1;
     }
}
```

This is a part of my code; how do I calculate the worst case time complexity of this? Since it involves random numbers, I felt it was complicated.
I came up with

```
f(n) = 1+1+1+1((n*1)+(n*1)) = 3+n+n = 3+2n
```

but I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: If we assume it is a real random number generator, it can keep going on forever. Since the generator could each time yield the same value, like 9, 9, 9, ... http://ardiri.com/blog/entries/20140901/random-dilbert.jpg

Comment: num is user input integer

Comment: well that is the upperbound of the range over which the random number generator can pick values. While it is extremely unlikely, worst case, it takes infinte time. As for average case: try to make a probability analysis of yielding the same number.

Comment: if its infinite how do I calculate big O